# Putting derived classes into STL maps as values

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, derived-class

I have 2 simple classes. Base class `A`, and a derived class `B`. For debugging purposes, copy constructor and destructor are overridden to `cout` stuff:

```
class A
{
protected:
    char * c;
public:
    A(char * c) : c(c) { cout << "+A " << this << "\n"; }
    A(const A& other) : c(other.c) { cout << "*A " << this << "\n"; }
    ~A() { cout << "-A " << this << "\n"; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(char * c) : A(c) { cout << "+B " << this << "\n"; }
    B(const B& other) : A(other.c) { cout << "*B " << this << "\n"; }
    ~B() { cout << "-B " << this << "\n"; }
};
```

Here's how I `insert` an instance of `B` into the `map`:

```
    {
        cout << "-- 1\n";
        map<string, A> m;
        cout << "-- 2\n";
        m.insert(pair<string, A>( "b", B("bVal")));
        cout << "-- 3\n";
    }
    cout << "-- 4 --\n";
```

The result of that:

```
-- 1
-- 2
+A 0051F620
+B 0051F620
*A 0051F5EC
*A 00BD8BAC
-A 0051F5EC
-B 0051F620
-A 0051F620
-- 3
-A 00BD8BAC
-- 4 --
```

As regards creation of instances, I read this as follows:

1. `B` gets created by my own code
2. that `B` gets copy-constructed into an `A` by `pair`
3. that last `A` instance then gets copied once more by the `map`, where it is inserted

Btw changing the `pair` in the `insert` line to a `pair<string, B>` did not do the trick, it only changed the 2nd step to create an `B` instead of the `A`, but the last step would *downgrade* it to an `A` again. The only instance in the map that remains until the map itself is eligible for destruction seems to be that last `A` instance.

What am I doing wrong and how am I supposed to get a derived class into a map? Use maps of the format

```
map<string, A*>
```

perhaps?

**Update - Solution** As my solution is not stated directly in the accepted answer, but rather buried in its comments in form of suggestions, here's what I ended up doing:

```
map<string, shared_ptr<A>> m;
```

This assumes your build environment supports `shared_ptr`s - which mine (C++/CLI, Visual Studio 2010) does.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: To avoid slicing and generate a compile error, make base classes abstract where possible.

Comment: You can just make the copy constructor protected also.

Comment: Why not use `make_pair`, instead of `pair<string, A>( ...` stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 map<string, A> m;
```

will **slice** the inserted object, which will become an `A`, losing all other information (it is no longer a `B`).

Your intuition is correct, you'll need to use pointers or, better yet, smart pointers.

Also, the destructor in `A` needs to be `virtual`:

```
class A
{
    //...
    virtual ~A() { cout << "-A " << this << "\n"; }
};
```

otherwise deleting an object of actual type `B` through a pointer to an `A` leads to **undefined behavior**.

Comment: +1 Thanks also for the destructor warning. If I do not provide a destructor (as I have done here only for debugging purposes) I guess the compiler would take care of that for me?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy in this case, no. You **need** a virtual destructor, even if it's empty.

Comment: Good to know. One last thing: Smart pointers aren't in the C++ standard until C++11, correct?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy I think there's `auto_ptr`, but I'd use something from boost.

Comment: Just to make that one clear: Don't use auto_ptr as elements in a container.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy Actually, there are some smart pointers in [TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1), which is supported by some compilers that don't support C++11 yet. For example, VS2008 (I think with SP1) has shared_ptr and weak_ptr.

Comment: @user331471 Thanks for the heads up. This would seem to not apply to `shared_ptr`, though, as mentioned by MikMik

Answer (score 4):

This is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) and happens when a derived class does not fit into the object it has been assigned to. This is the tirivial example:

```
B b;
A a = b; // This would only copy the A part of B.
```

If you want to store different types of object in a map, using map<..., A*> is the way to go, as you correctly deduced. Since the object is not stored inside the map but rather somewhere on the heap, there is no need to copy it and it always fits.